# Bug rendering text in canvas in Windows

Tags: html, canvas

i'm making an application that uses text rendering in canvas and I have encounter a weird problem. I have tested in many computers and it only occurs on systems with Windows. I'll explain it:

When I use Times New Roman, with somes font sizes, with a fill color, a text stroke and in italic style, some letters display the stroke displaced.

At first I thought it was a problem with the library that I was using for canvas, but I have tested with native canvas and it is happening too.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekm3o977/1/ (Remember that it only happens in Windows)

```
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = 80;
      var y = 110;

      context.font = 'italic 70px Times New Roman';

      context.lineWidth = 1;
      // stroke color
      context.strokeStyle = 'red';
      context.fillStyle = 'blue';
      context.fillText('abcdefghijklmnñ', x, y);
      context.strokeText('abcdefghijklmnñ', x, y);
      context.fillText('opqrstuvwxyz', x, y+100);
      context.strokeText('opqrstuvwxyz', x, y+100);
    </script>
</body>
```

Any thoughts of how can it be solved? Thanks

Comment: Here's confirming the displacement on Win8.1 IE11, Chrome39 & FF33.  As a workaround, you might use a webfont Times New Roman instead of the system font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cause for this cannot be solved as it is internal issues with the sub-system (which the browsers interact with) with this typeface itself.

You can try a couple of approaches though:

1. As mentioned in the comments, try to use a web-font version of it (note: [requires license](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/times-new-roman?QueryFontType=Web&src=GoogleWebFonts#product_top)). For canvas you will need to use a [font-loader](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader) so you know when the font has loaded properly before drawing the text to canvas.
2. I noticed that the problem goes away at size 100px exactly. We can use that to make a wrapper function to scale it to the size we need. I have taken a couple of compromises in my solution below such as dropping baseline and alignment. You can however expand it with those if you need it.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.font = "italic 70px Times New Roman";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.fillText("This is native fillText/strokeText", 10, 10);
ctx.strokeText("This is native fillText/strokeText", 10, 10);

tnrWrapper(ctx, "This is wrapper function", 10, 80, 70, "italic");

function tnrWrapper(ctx, txt, x, y, size, style) {

  var width, hf = 1.1, // height factor
      tcanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
      tctx = tcanvas.getContext("2d");

  style = style || ""; // italic, bold or nothing
  
  tctx.font = style + " 100px Times New Roman"; // fixed at 100px here  
  width = tctx.measureText(txt).width;
  
  tcanvas.width = width; // this will reset font, optionally set a fixed width
  tcanvas.height = 100*hf;  // todo: find a better proportional factor

  tctx.font = style + " 100px Times New Roman";  // new width resets context
  tctx.textBaseline = "top";
  tctx.textAlign = "start";  // rtl sensitive, or use left/right
  
  tctx.lineWidth = ctx.lineWidth * (100/size);   // scale line width
  tctx.fillStyle = ctx.fillStyle;
  tctx.strokeStyle = ctx.strokeStyle;

  tctx.fillText(txt, 0, 0);
  tctx.strokeText(txt, 0, 0);
  
  ctx.drawImage(tcanvas, x, y, width * (size/100), 100*hf * (size/100));
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width=600 height=180></canvas>
```

As you can see we now get approximate the same size but without the alignment problem.

Note 1: fonts do not behave linearly in size. They are optimized for displaying at individual sizes. This will affect the actual width etc. so don't expect them to be identical at all sizes. But it should provide a working solution until there is a fix for this problem (which may take a while as it seem to be system level in Windows).

Note 2: the font is set twice. This is because we need to measure it and update canvas to match. When canvas gets a new dimension context is reset loosing the set font. You can avoid this by setting a fixed width of canvas.

Hope this helps!